# display count of times the number has been entered

Tags: java, increment

im doing an excercise, it wants to display the number of times the user has entered the number till he enter -1 which breaks the program. I can't think of a way to add it. I'd like you to add a variable which will store the number of times user entered a number and display it at the bottom

```
    System.out.println("Type numbers:");
    
    int sum = 0;
    
    while(true) {   
        int number = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
        if(number == -1) {
            break;
        }
        
        sum += number;
        
    } 
    
    System.out.println("Thank you and see you later");
    System.out.println("The sum of the numbers is "+sum);
}
```

}

Comment: '_I can't think of a way to add it._' - you are already doing similar operation by summing up all inputs so what's the difference and what's the problem?

Comment: why don\`t you use a hashmap or something like that to store the count?

Comment: use another variable that you increase of 1 in the loop ?

Comment: the difference is that sum variable is for the sum of the all numbers entered and other one is for the how many times user has entered the number. Suppose i write 5,3,2,-1 the sum would be 10 and the other variable would be 3 which is the number of inputs entered. Is it understandable? i cant come with a way to make it possible

Comment: create another variable: int count = 0, before the while statement. after calculating sum += number; also do: count++;. In the end, the count variable will be equal to the number of times the user inputed a number not equal to -1

Comment: @FireBoy Glad you solved it.  Now you can post and accept an Answer to your own Question, for posterity.

Answer (score 1):

Solution of the problem is already given in the comment section. I'm just adding it as an answer with code.

Solution:

Maintain another variable to count the number of given inputs.

Code:

```
System.out.println("Type numbers:");

int sum = 0;
int inputCount = 0;

while (true) {
    int number = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
    if (number == -1) {
        break;
    }
    inputCount++;   // incrementing number of valid input
    sum += number;
}

System.out.println("Thank you and see you later");
System.out.println("The sum of the numbers is " + sum);
System.out.println("Count of given input " + inputCount);
```